# Password auth Error on a localhost pgdatabase running on docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, operationalerror

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

I expect a successful connection, however that has not been the case. Docker containers are up and running but I am unable to create that connection using:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}", echo_pool="debug")
con = engine.connect()
```

I have verified login credentials over and over and I still don't understand/know how to get pass this.

Comment: Note that the username/password variables on the postgres container are only used if no database exists when the container starts. If a database already exists, you have to use a username/password that exists in the database.

Comment: Also 'localhost' can be misleading. Network-wise the host running a container and the container itself are on different networks - unless specified differently at startup.